# Получение значений локального массива функции

Tags: python

Как получить значения my_array с вне. Интересует вывод на экран аргументов функции, которые функция может отработать по особенному, в других случаях всё будет по общему алгоритму

```
def foo( args ):
    my_array = ["Arg1", "Arg2"]     

for x in foo:my_array:
    print str(x)
```

Comment: код в вопросе не является Питоном. Словами опишите, что вы пытаетесь сделать с явным примером ввода, желаемого вывода. После возвращения из функции локальные переменные можно считать уже не существуют. Не ясно что вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score -1):

Не уверен что правильно вас понял. Но думаю это подойдёт.

```
def foo( *args ):
    my_array = [args]
    return my_array
for x in foo('Arg1', 'Arg2', 'Arg3'):
    print(str(x))
```

Результат:

```
('Arg1', 'Arg2', 'Arg3')
```